# Type 'NodeListOf<HTMLImageElement>' must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to loop throught images of type `NodeListOf<HTMLImageElement>` to get images from text/html type and I'm getting an error: Type '`NodeListOf<HTMLImageElement>`' must have a '`[Symbol.asyncIterator]()`' method..

```
let doc = parser.parseFromString(translation, 'text/html');
let imgs = doc.body.querySelectorAll("img");

for await (let img of imgs) {//                     <--- error happens here
  const imgBase64 = img.src.split(',')[1];
  const genericImgBase64Name = imgBase64.slice(40, 45) + (Math.round(Math.random() * 100000));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove `await` from the for loop?

Comment: @R.Richards nope, error just changes to: must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method.

Comment: Does it work if you use the regular document.body.querySelectorAll? I think your `doc` is something else than you might think it is.

Comment: @Joost00719 `doc` the DOM [from a parsed string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString), so `document.body` will not be targetting it. If you receive the string `<div id="parent"><p id="child"></p></div>` then using `document.querySelector("#parent")` will not find those elements.

Comment: I think I've found the solution. Try setting your TS compiler to es6 or higher. (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726742/7081176)

Comment: I wouldnt personally change ts compiler config just to allow this one method. I would go with `forEach` or `for` loop.

Comment: @kinduser it's weird because TS complains *but compiles it correctly* to a regular `for` loop. [See playground here](https://tsplay.dev/N7oZBN). The compiled code on the right is correct. The error seems out of place.

Comment: @VLAZ when using `const foo: number = true` ts complains but still correctly compiles to `const foo = true` :P

Comment: @kinduser Yes, but that's a logical error. Causing the code to not be sound. Transpilation to a lower ES level would not be a logical error. TS does not complain for using `for..of` on an array - because the code *is* semantically transferrable. A `for..of` can be cleanly and *correctly* re-written for an array. Similarly, it is semantically transferrable for a NodeList yet TS does throw a compilation error, even though the transpiled code should be the same. It can't be either/or here - if it complains about anything, it should also complain about arrays as there is no iterator in ES5.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, fully agree

Comment: @kinduser if I change it to forEach, it throws no error but nothing happens either. Like loop doesn't exist.

Comment: @DarioLucić Loop doesnt exist? Did you try to console.log anything inside `forEach`?

Comment: @kinduser yes, nothing prints

Comment: @DarioLucić Does the array has any content? `console.log(imgs)`;

Comment: @kinduser yes it prints [object NodeList]

Comment: @DarioLucić Did you remove the `await` keyword?

Comment: @kinduser yes it's removed

Comment: @DarioLucić Not sure how to help you, tried the same and it works for me, even if the `for...of` approach didnt.

Comment: @kinduser you tried it also on NodeList?

Comment: @DarioLucić Yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, just add `"dom.iterable"` to `"lib"` section in tsconfig.json file.